# iOS - Archive item is not associated with any known iTunes Connect platform

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm trying to validate my in-app purchase content package so I'd be able to upload it to iTunesConnect.

But when I click validate I get this error:

> Archive item is not associated with any known iTunes Connect platform.

I already created a non-consumable product in iTunesConnect and made sure that the product ID is the same as IAPProductIdentifier.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I used Application Loader instead and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

For googlers who end up here and can't figure it out, here's how I got it to work with Xcode 8.2 and Application Loader 3.6 (Xcode menu > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader)

First, make sure you have your app registered with Apple iTunesConnect and you have created the in-app product as a non-consumable product with Content Hosting turned on.  The in-app product will probably be in a Waiting for Upload status.

Create a new Xcode project, change the type to Cross-platform and choose the In-App Purchase Content template.  The product name and organization information does not really matter because you're going to change them. Save the project.

With the new project open, make sure the project root is selected on the navigator panel, then choose the General tab.  Change the Product ID to match the Product ID you configured in iTunes Connect.  This must match!

Drag and drop your content files into the project.... movies, images, whatever content you're delivering with this in-app product.  If it is not executable (its a movie for example) ensure that it is not be part of the Target Membership.

Next, archive it using the Product > Archive menu.  The Organizer for archives will open.  Highlight your archive and choose Export on the right.  Export it as an Installer Package. Save it anywhere you can find it later.

Open Application Loader, sign in, choose your app and click Manage.  On the In-App Purchases panel find and highlight the product.  Assuming you have Content Hosting enabled you will see a panel at the bottom for Hosted Content.  Open Hosted Content and choose the Installer Package you created earlier.

Switch to the Delivery panel (at top) and click Deliver.  A few minutes after the loader finishes successfully, you will see your product in iTunesConnect has the package associated to it.

To actually download and use the content in your app, you will need to call  SKPaymentQueue startDownloads and implement the updatedDownloads observer... which is a different question entirely.

For reference, the Application Loader doc is here but it does not explain all of the information above:
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf